# Add checkmark on click, on multiple pics

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 9 pictures displayed in table cells in one row,what I'm trying to do is when I click on picture check mark will show in front of pic.If I click again checkmark will hide.If I click second pic checkmark will also show on that pic and checkmark on first pic also remains displayed.Same goes for third, fourth and so on...

Comment: put your code, please.

Comment: Code bellow is same as mine...

Answer (score 3):

You can put something like this:

```html
<label>
  <img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lin/128/1.png'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</label>
<label>
  <img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lin/128/1.png'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</label>
<label>
  <img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lin/128/1.png'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</label>
<label>
  <img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lin/128/1.png'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
</label>
```

Comment: That's ok,but can I hide checkboxes and instead on click show only check mark on center of pic?